# Parsing and converting to Hash of CSV file in Ruby returns an integer

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

I'm trying to import a CSV file in a vanilla ruby command line app and based on docs I've read on parsing CSV files, I'm using the following:

```
def self.import
  family_preferences = []
     CSV.foreach(File.path("path/to/my_csv_file.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
        family_preferences << row.to_h
      end
   end
end
```

When I evoke this by calling a class method or as an imported module, the return value is an Integer. Unless I actually `puts` Class.new.import or Module.import, where I can see the parsed table in terminal, it's only type Integer.

Class.new.import.class is Integer or
Module.import.class is Integer

Answer (score 1):

You missed to return `family_preferences` like:

```rb
   def self.import
     family_preferences = []
     CSV.foreach(File.path("path/to/my_csv_file.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
        family_preferences << row.to_h
      end

      family_preferences
   end
```

Ruby returns the last line executed. In your snippet, it was returning the return of foreach function, which is an integer. Place the filled variable and you will get what you want

Comment: You could write `CSV.foreach(File.path("path/to/my_csv_file.csv"), headers: true).with_object([]) do |row, family_preferences| ... end` and remove the first and last line of the body of the method.

Comment: Or `family_preferences = CSV.table("path/to/my_csv_file.csv").map(:&to_h)`